# Matlab: Using a matrix as a mask to perform elementwise operations

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have two matrices: one with integers,`x`, and one with booleans, `y`:

```
x =

     2     4     2
     3     3     1
     4     1     5

y =

     0     0     1
     1     1     0
     1     0     1
```

What I now want to do is to assign some elements of `x` to 5, and I want to use `y` as a mask to determine which elements should be set to 5. So elements with a corresponding value of 0 in `y` should remain as they are in `x`, but those with a corresponding value of 1 in `y` should be set to 5. Therefore, the output should be:

```
     2     4     5
     5     5     1
     5     1     5
```

I have tried the following:

```
x(y) = 5
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

And I have also tried:

```
y(x) = 5
```

Which gives me the following:

```
 5     5     1
 5     1     0
 5     0     1
```

Can somebody please explain what is going on here, and what I need to do to get my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you've got is due to the fact that, apparently, `y` is of `type double` while, in this case, it should be of `type logical`

You could try:

```
x(logical(y))=5
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Even shorter: `x(y==1)=5;`

Comment: @rayryeng - your suggestion is way too long. `x(~~y)=5;` ;)

Comment: I think it's helpful to point out the conceptual difference between a double (or any numeric data type for that matter)  `0` and a logical `0` when indexing: a double index means "go to the array at position `0` __which doesn't exist__ and return the appropriate value. Whereas [logical indexing is more like "this one yes, this one not"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24900837#24900837) - or in other words, it has the meaning of whether an elements was referenced. I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: @Dev-iL - 100% agree.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a fancy solution but will solve your problem

```
>> x = [  2     4     2;3     3     1;4     1     5];
y = logical([  0     0     1;1     1     0;1     0     1]);
f = x(:);
f(y(:)) = 5;
x = reshape(f,size(x))

x =

     2     4     5
     5     5     1
     5     1     5

>>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  `y` is still a `double` array with values of 0 and you should get an error at the second statement.  You can only slice into arrays using numeric arrays that are indexed starting at 1, or are `logical` arrays.

Comment: Now that you added `logical` it works.  You didn't have that before.  Removing downvote.  You should probably double check your answers before posting.

Comment: Ok... The title of you question says :
"In Matlab, I have two matrices: one with integers,x, and one with booleans, y:" 

BOOLEANS y i think it was implicit that y was a logical array.

Answer (score -1):

`x(find(y)) = 5;` should work fine.

Comment: `find` is overkill in this case.  Using logical indexing is better suited.... i.e. `x(y==1)=5;`.